# FBConnect using Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, fbconnect

I start to use FBConnect module to my Drupal site.

FBConnect readme says

1. Create a new facebook application: http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php
2. Enter the Site URL on Web Site settings tab (e.g. copy value from **admin/settings/fbconnect** field “Connect url”).
3. Configure the module through **admin interface (admin/settings/fbconnect)** using the information provided by Facebook
   (Application ID, Application Secret).

Even i try to type this as URL in browser:
http://ph7.localhost:8082/admin/settings/fbconnect
Noting happens.
Sadly, i found this in Module section :
Requires: Fbconnect (disabled), Libraries (missing).

I am pretty sure i have **copy** file to sites\all\modules\fbconnect and also
**create** a directory "libraries" which yield :sites\all\libraries\facebook-php-sdk

Question: 1.where is admin/settings/fbconnect ?
2.how to install fbconnect module for drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to re-check/verify each and every point [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/fbconnect.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/master:/README.TXT)

> In order for the user's browser to correctly recognize XFBML tags, you need to specify that the page is in XHTML. 
>       Edit the "page.tpl.php" file of your current theme. edit the  tag and add the facebook xmlns for rendering XFBML.

In case you need FB Connect module only for registration and login, I suggest to try [FBOauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) module.

It does not require any library and has a **stable version** in D7.

Answer (score 1):

The message that it requires "Libraries" pertains to the [Libraries API module](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) (short name: libraries), which provides some code that many other modules depend on. It doesn't do *anything* on its own, but the hooks/functions in that module are used by so many other modules that it's something like the 20th most installed Drupal module, so you'll likely end up finding it's required for other modules you want to activate.

I suspect that you saw this message that a module "Requires: Fbconnect (disabled), Libraries (missing)" in one of the sub-modules of [Fbconnect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect), which provides additional Facebook-related features (e.g. the Facebook Friends Invite sub-module of Fbconnect). **The main Fbconnect module is in the "Authentication" section of your `admin/modules/list` page.** You need to install and activate the Libraries API module, *then* turn on the Fbconnect main module, *then* you can turn on the other Facebook connect sub-modules, if you like.

Hope that helps. :-)